# How To Eliminate Duplicates of Coordinates from A List?

Tags: python, list, numpy, python-requests

I have got a code which keeps adding if length of a line is longer than a limit. Basically lets say you have got some lines with their start and end points. And your limit is 400. My code helps you to decide if each one of these lines are longer than the limit or not. My input is here. I should eliminate those duplicates.

`def kolon_uzaklik_testi(aday_kolon,limit_kolon_mesafesi):`

```
for x in range(len(aday_kolon)):
    for j in range(len(aday_kolon)):
        kolonlar_arasi_mesafe = math.sqrt(math.pow((round(aday_kolon[j][0],40)-round(aday_kolon[x][0],40)),2)+math.pow((round(aday_kolon[j][1], 40)-round(aday_kolon[x][1],40)),2))
        if kolonlar_arasi_mesafe >= limit_kolon_mesafesi:
            print('distance_between',round(aday_kolon[x][0],40),'and',round(aday_kolon[j][0],40),'over the limit')
```

kolon_uzaklik_testi(list_ko_ki,500)

```
`
Here is my code: Output for this code is: 
`distance_between 2623.0846284244976 and 3338.2551982893056 over the limit
distance_between 3041.4346691784417 and 2686.9605725785777 over the limit
distance_between 3041.4346691784417 and 3338.2551982893056 over the limit
distance_between 2686.9605725785777 and 3041.4346691784417 over the limit
distance_between 2686.9605725785777 and 3338.2551982893056 over the limit
distance_between 3338.2551982893056 and 2623.0846284244976 over the limit
distance_between 3338.2551982893056 and 3041.4346691784417 over the limit
distance_between 3338.2551982893056 and 2686.9605725785777 over the limit`
```

`
    I dont want to see duplicates of the coordinates. If they are the same coordinate.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please share a clear example of your input, expected output and the code you have tried so far?

Comment: I added it below

Comment: You should edit your question instead of adding an answer

Comment: Fixed it, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you do not want the same coordinates (in any order) to appear again

I modified your code snippet to keep only unique sets of coordinates

```
coord_list = []
for x in range(len(aday_kolon)):
    for j in range(len(aday_kolon)):
        kolonlar_arasi_mesafe = math.sqrt(math.pow((round(aday_kolon[j][0],40)-round(aday_kolon[x][0],40)),2)+math.pow((round(aday_kolon[j][1], 40)-round(aday_kolon[x][1],40)),2))
        if kolonlar_arasi_mesafe >= limit_kolon_mesafesi:
            # store coordinates as tuples in a list
            coord_list.append(round(aday_kolon[x][0],40), round(aday_kolon[j][0],40))

# keep only unique values
unique_vals = []
for i in coord_list:
    if not ((i[0], i[1]) in unique_vals or (i[1], i[0]) in unique_vals):  # skip if tuple already appears (elements in any order)
        unique_vals.append(i)

for output in unique_vals:
    print('distance_between',output[0],'and',output[1],'over the limit')
```

Comment: That works amazing. Thank you so much! I appreciate it